# behaviour of LOCK TABLE table_name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE in oracle v/s Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, locking

After applying the lock on table using below command in oracle DB:

```
$db->do("LOCK TABLE table_name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE") or ataerr::dbexecute($db);
```

I updated one of it's index tablespace  using below command:

```
$db->do("ALTER INDEX i_charge MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES TABLESPACE tablespace2") or ataerr::dbexecute($db);
```

Since the table was locked i got following error:

> The current partition operation has failed with ORACLE error: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 12 in 'ALTER INDEX <*>I_CHARGE MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES TABLESPACE CHARGE_IND').
> Retrying in 2 seconds.

I am trying to do same operation in postgres DB, but it is **not throwing any error**.

I have updated index tablespace using following command in postgres:

```
ALTER INDEX i_charge SET TABLESPACE CHARGE;
```

I have inspected lock on table using following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pg_locks pl 
LEFT JOIN pg_stat_activity psa
    ON pl.pid = psa.pid;
```

Output from above query shows the is AccessShareLock held on the table.

Please help me what should I do so that it throws error message in Postgres?

Comment: Are you sure "ALTER INDEX i_charge MODIFY" is valid syntax for PostgreSQL? It's not in the manual.

Comment: sorry, I have used following  syntax in postgres:  ALTER INDEX i_charge SET TABLESPACE CHARGE

Comment: Note that tablespace are rarely used in Postgres to begin with (and usually not needed either). The use case for them between Oracle and Postgres is **very** different.

Comment: actually, I have altered the index's tablespace just to show that when table is locked, it should block index tablespace operation.

Comment: Why do you want an error when nothing went wrong and there is no error? Send some invalid piece of SQL to your database and you get an error message. PostgreSQL and Oracle are both databases but their behaviour can be different and this is one example.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the index table space does not require a lock on the table in PostgreSQL, so it is unsurprising that the lock on the table does not block it.

Comment: thanks for the reply @laurenz Albe.  It's blocking in oracle but not in postgres. what should i do so that it block in postgres as well?

Comment: Lock the table? But usually, when people take explicit table locks, they are doing something wrong.

Comment: Why do you want lock even though **it is not necessary**. Apparently, your contention *to show that when table is locked, it should block index tablespace operation.* is wrong in Postgres.